# How to perform data driven load testing using LoadUI

Tags: user-interface, loadui

I am load testing a web service.

Is it possible to perform data driven testing using loadui? If yes, how?

We can just give requests to web runner (where url is given) but I am not able to feed any data.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://loadui.org/Load-Testing-soapUI-Tests/getting-started-with-soapui-integration.html) article in the loadUI documentation explains how you do it. Basically, you have to use a soapUI DataSource via the soapUI Runner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SoapUI & LoadUI [with free versions :-) ]

In SoapUI create a TestSuite, then create TestCase. In TestCase define custom property... for example property with name "firstName"

Then in your request you can use values like this 
${#TestCase#firstName}

Save a project and open LoadUI.

click on FLOW -> choose DataSource
Browse your input file. Right Click -> settings , modify separator for your needs.
check loop option to TRUE.

After that, you can use some Runner, right click on it -> Settings -> Properties

Now you can see all TestCase Properties (defined in SoapUI).

Now u need just to make transfer from datasource to SoapUIRunner
For column value you can use someting like this:
${#Data Source 1#firstName}\

Hope this helps.
Cheers
Nikola